# getting a specific line from a csv file based on a value from that line (and not the line number) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, csv, dom, find

my goal is very simple, i want to create a website with an input box and a send button where a user would write a name and the website will fetch the info from a csv file.

for example:
suppose this is my csv file:

```
name,value1
roy,2
dani,3
gabe,6
nick,5
```

and the user input is "gabe" so I need to show a popup with "6".

the constrain is that i don't know that gabe is in line 2.

i basically need a "find" or "in" func for a csv file.
keep in mind that my csv is very large, it has about 19240 rows and has 90 columns (I will try to shrink it).

i saw a solution that converted the csv file to an array in JavaScript but he was only able to access a line by its line number and i dont know in which line a specific name is saved, and i also think loading this entire table would take a while so im not sure if converting the csv to an array will be a good solution.

thanks for anyone who helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get it into an array then you can use [find](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp) or [findindex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp) or [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) functions to get the required line number